# Scroll to specific cell in UITableView with cell property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have an example of `UITableViewCell` as below:

```
//
//  ItemTableViewCell.h
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ItemTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *itemId;

@end
```

In my `UIViewController` with `UITableView` I have the below assigning :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSManagedObject *row = [self.itemsFRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    ItemTableViewCell *cell = (ItemTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.itemId = [row valueForKey:@"item_id"];
}
```

Now, how can I scroll to specific cell in `UITableView` with it's cell property `itemId`?

Note: I highly prefer to not to use `indexPathForRow` method.

Comment: get the index of the `itemId` in `self.itemsFRC` then use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` to that index of row and section and you are good to go

Comment: `self.itemsFRC` is not reliable in my case. I couldn't use that. I have only cells with itemId

Comment: Then before that put all the itemID to an array instead of using that `self.itemsFRC` to populate your cell

Comment: @Tj3n Could you please write your code in an answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what's your `itemsFRC ` is, is it coredata array?

Comment: @Tj3n FetchedResultController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do the following:

1. Find `NSManagedObject` by `item_id`
2. Get `indexPath` of found object from `NSFetchedResultsController`
3. Scroll `tableView` to that `indexPath`

See code example below:

```
- (void) scrollToRowWithItemID: (NSString *) itemID {
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = self.itemsFRC.fetchedObjects;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"item_id == %@", itemID];
    NSArray *filteredArray = [fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.itemsFRC indexPathForObject: filteredArray.firstObject];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: indexPath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated: true];   
}
```

Comment: Great, do you know another way without relying on `self.itemsFRC`?

Comment: It depends on your use case. When do you need to scroll your table view?

Comment: I want to scroll based on `itemId` of cell itself, something like looking up in cells instead of checking `NSFetchResultController`, is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get what do you want.